# MATLAB: atan2 breaking ode15s

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a program that runs ode15s a few thousand times in order to find a particular solution. However, I'm getting many integration tolerance errors such as the following:

`"Warning: Failure at t=5.144337e+02.  Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (1.818989e-12) at time t."`

Such warnings cause the program to slow down drastically, and sometimes even grind to a complete halt. The following is some test code that re-produces the error:

```
%Simulation constants
G = 6.672e-11; %Gravitational constant
M = 6.39e23; %Mass of Mars (kg)
g = 9.81; %Gravitational acceleration on Earth (m/s^2);
T1 = 845000/3; %Total engine thrust, 1 engine (N)
Isp = 282; %Engine specific impulse (s)
mdot1 = T1/(g*Isp); %Engine mass flow rate (kg/s)
xinit_on2 = [72368.8347685214;
            3384891.40103322;
            -598.36623436025;
            -1440.49702235844;
            16330.430678033]
tspan_on2 = [436.600093957202, 520.311296453027];
[t3,x3] = ode15s(@(t,x) engine_on_2(t, x, G, g, M, Isp, T1), tspan_on2, xinit_on2)
```

where the function `engine_on_2` contains the system of ODEs that model the descent of a rocket, and is given by,

```
function xdot = engine_on_2(t, x, G, g, M, Isp, T1)
gamma = atan2(x(4),x(3)); %flight-path angle
xdot = [x(3); %xdot1: x-velocity
        x(4); %xdot2: y-velocity
        -(G*M*x(1))/((x(1)^2+x(2)^2)^(3/2))-(T1/x(5))*cos(gamma); %xdot3: x-acceleration
        -(G*M*x(2))/((x(1)^2+x(2)^2)^(3/2))-(T1/x(5))*sin(gamma); %xdot4: y-acceleration
        -T1/(g*Isp)]; %xdot5: engine mass flow rate
end
```

Having done some testing, it seems that I am getting the integration tolerance warnings because of the use of the atan2 function in `gamma = atan2(x(4),x(3))` which is used to calculate the flight-path angle of the rocket. If I change atan2 to another function (for example cos or sin) I don't get any integration tolerance warnings anymore (although, due to such a change, my solutions are obviously incorrect). As such, I was wondering if I am using atan2 incorrectly, or if there is a way to implement it differently so that I do not get the integration tolerance errors anymore. Furthermore, could it be that I am incorrect and that it is something other than atan2 that is causing the errors?

Comment: check the posted solution and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `odeset` function to create an options structure that you then pass to the solver. `RelTol` and `AbsTol` can be adjusted in the ODE solver to eliminate your error.  I was able to run your code using this addition without any errors:

```
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-13,'AbsTol',1e-20)

[t3,x3] = ode15s(@(t,x) engine_on_2(t, x, G, g, M, Isp, T1), tspan_on2, xinit_on2, options)
```

See the `options` are passed to the ODE solver as a 4th input parameter.  Note the `RelTol` maxes out just above 1e-13 but hopefully that's fine for your application.  Also you can try any of the other ODE solvers which can get rid of your error but from my playing around `ode15s` seems quite fast.